# How to move from line to line using VI

Tags: putty

I am using PuTTY to connect to my CentOS shell server. My only problem is the keyboard I currently use is a 60%. Meaning I have no arrow keys... Darn. How could i move around the shell without arrow keys? Thanks. If you are not familiar with PuTTy, it's just a way to connect to a server like a regular command prompt.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Please add a bit more detail. A way to move around the shell without an arrow key is by typing commands.

Comment: Sorry, I am using the text editor, VI. http://www.howtogeek.com/102468/a-beginners-guide-to-editing-text-files-with-vi/ I am asking if the only way to move my cursors selection once I change to insert mode is by using arrow keys.

Comment: `J` move cursor down one line
`K` move cursor up one                                                                                                            `I` move cursor left one character
`H` move cursor right one character

Comment: @FrancescStudio thank you for taking the time to write that out! Your answer confirmed my statement below. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution! You are actually supposed to use HKJL to move around in command mode! Not the arrow keys. Reason listed below. 
https://superuser.com/questions/599150/why-arrow-keys-are-not-recommended-in-vim

Answer (score 0):

- `J` move cursor down one line
- `K` moves cursor up
- `H` moves cursor right
- `I` moves cursor left

Make sure to take a look at the help manual if you're starting with VI because if for example you want to go to the end of the line at line 40 you don't want to press `J` 40 times and then go to the end of the line or if you're looking for an specific line or word you can use `/string`

*Reference*: 
http://glaciated.org/vi/